# MPMoviePlayerController H.264 and Multiple Audio Streams

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpeg-4

I am trying to find some information on how to support multiple audio streams from a single H.264/MPEG4 video file.

So far I have found very little information when googling, I was wondering if anybody has any information that may shed some light.

I would like to display the video then have a choice of which audio stream to play from the H.264 format.

Anybody?

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController does not support that.

Comment: Can you explain how it can be done then?

Comment: In case you are taklking about local files, AVPlayer would be the tool to cover it. For proper HTTP-streaming (M3U8) I am afraid I have no answer for you.

Comment: Its local files which have multiple audio tracks (for language purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPMoviePlayer cannot be used to play a movie with multiple audio streams.