# Switch between audio tracks in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller

In the app I'm currently working on I have some videos with multiple audio tracks (in different languages) and I'd like to have the ability to switch between these tracks programmatically. There is a button that allows the user to switch between them manually (which presents this screen by tapping on it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkUTZ.png) so I assumed this wouldn't be too hard. However, after two hours of research I haven't found anything useful. There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138380/mpmovieplayercontroller-h-264-and-multiple-audio-streams) StackOverflow question that suggests it's impossible to play video with multiple audio streams in the first place, but apparently that doesn't stand true anymore. There are also some examples with `AVFoundation` (I haven't really looked into the), but none with `MPMoviePlayer` or `MPMoviePlayerController`.

So I'd like to know if my goal is achievable with stock `MPMoviePlayerController` and if not, what are the good alternatives to it.